# MAC OS: The Apache Tomcat Native library which allows using OpenSSL was not found

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, maven, tomcat

I have added all the spring jars in build path.
When I'm trying to run a simple dependency injection program on Eclipse, it doesn't show output in console. I'm using macOS. So please give a solution for MAC perspective.

Here is my console output:

```
Jul 25, 2023 12:32:50 PM org.apache.catalina.startup. VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=/Users/PR20372898/eclipse-workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmpo/wtpwebapps
Jul 25, 2023 12:32:50 PM org.apache.catalina.startup. Version LoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: --add-opens-java.base/java.lang-ALL-UNNAMED
Jul 25, 2023 12:32:50 PM org.apache.catalina.startup. Version LoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: --add-opens-java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED
Jul 25, 2023 12:32:50 PM org.apache.catalina.startup. Version LoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: --add-opens-java.base/java.util-ALL-UNNAMED
Jul 25, 2023 12:32:50 PM org.apache.catalina.startup. Version LoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: --add-opens-java.base/java.util.concurrent-ALL-UNNAMED
Jul 25, 2023 12:32:50 PM org.apache.catalina.startup. Version LoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: --add-opens-java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport-ALL-UNNAMED
Jul 25, 2023 12:32:50 PM org.apache.catalina.startup. Version LoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
Jul 25, 2023 12:32:50 PM org.apache.catalina.startup. VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Xbootclasspath/a:/Users/PR20372898/apache-tomcat-9.0.63/bin/bootstrap.jar:/Users/PR20372898/apache-tomcat-9.0.63/bin/commons-daemon.jar:/Users/PR20372898/apac
Jul 25, 2023 12:32:50 PM org.apache.catalina.startup. Version LoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -XX: +ShowCodeDetailsInExceptionMessages
Jul 25, 2023 12:32:50 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: The Apache Tomcat Native library which allows using OpenSSL was not found on the java.library.path: [/Users/PR20372898/Library/Java/Extensions:/Library/Java/Extensions:/Network/Libra
Jul 25, 2023 12:32:51 PM org.apache.coyote. Abstract Protocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Jul 25, 2023 12:32:51 PM org.apache.catalina.startup. Catalina load
INFO: Server initialization in [335] milliseconds
Jul 25, 2023 12:32:51 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service [Catalina]
startInternal
Jul 25, 2023 12:32:51 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine
INFO: Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.63]
Jul 25, 2023 12:32:51 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet. TldScanner scanJars
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARS that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skippi
Jul 25, 2023 12:32:51 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet. TldScanner scanJars
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARS that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skippi
Jul 25, 2023 12:32:51 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet. TldScanner scanJars
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARS that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skippi
Jul 25, 2023 12:32:51 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARS that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skippi
Jul 25, 2023 12:32:51 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet. TldScanner scanJars
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARS that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skippi
Jul 25, 2023 12:32:52 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet. TldScanner scanJars
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARS that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skippi
Jul 25, 2023 12:32:52 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet. TldScanner scanJars
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARS that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skippi
Jul 25, 2023 12:32:52 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet. TldScanner scanJars
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARS that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skippi
Jul 25, 2023 12:32:52 PM org.apache.coyote. Abstract Protocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Jul 25, 2023 12:32:52 PM org.apache.catalina.startup. Catalina start
```

Here is my code:

```java
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans
xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
https://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">
<bean id = "student" class="com.seleniumexpress.Student">
<property name="id" value = "3100"></property>
<property name = "studentName" value = "Prajal Saxena"></property>
</bean>
<bean id = "student1" class="com.seleniumexpress. Student">
<constructor-arg name = "studentName" value = "Piyush Verma"></constructor-arg>
<constructor-arg name="id" value="3097"></constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

```java
package com.JFSTraining.SpringAssignments;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
public class Test
public static void main(String[] args) {}
}
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("beans.xml");
Student s1 = context.getBean("student", Student.class);
s1.displayStudentInfo();
Student s2 = context.getBean("student1", Student.class);
s2.displayStudentInfo();
```

it looks same things like this: [Test.java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JLh0Y.jpg)

Comment: It is just an informational message which you can ignore.

Comment: Im not getting output on console. trying to print student details in output. but console shows this error message

Comment: It is not an error message it is an informational message and doesn't influence your application. That you don't see any output is a totally different issue.

Comment: why system.out.println() not showing up op on console. Any idea?

Comment: That is a different question, ask that as a separate question don't re-use this one (or rewrite it to make it about that). Also don't post code as images but include them as code in the question. Looking at the logging output why are you even starting tomcat? This code isn't webrelated, just launch the `main` method.